# AWS Mobile Built-in Sign In issues

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using the given AutheticatorActivity code and have not made any changes to the UI in the user pool console itself.

When I run the app, every field in both log in and sign up pages are blank along with other issues like incomplete "Enter your information to sign up" message and "SignUpActivity" message on the sign up button.

Why is this happening? Screenshots and code below.

```
public class AuthenticatorActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_authenticator);

        final IdentityManager identityManager = AWSProvider.getInstance().getIdentityManager();
        // Set up the callbacks to handle the authentication response
        identityManager.login(this, new DefaultSignInResultHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Activity activity, IdentityProvider identityProvider) {
                Toast.makeText(AuthenticatorActivity.this,
                        String.format("Logged in as %s", identityManager.getCachedUserID()),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Go to the main activity
                final Intent intent = new Intent(activity, BottomNavMain.class)
                        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                activity.startActivity(intent);
                activity.finish();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCancel(Activity activity) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Start the authentication UI
        AuthUIConfiguration config = new AuthUIConfiguration.Builder()
                .userPools(true)
                .build();
        SignInActivity.startSignInActivity(this, config);
        AuthenticatorActivity.this.finish();
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post the contents in the Application.java class? Did you call identityManager.resumeSession(..) from any other class/activity? Can you check for any exception/error in Logcat window?

Comment: @Karthikeyan No exceptions/errors that I can find. My Application.java only has  `AWSProvider.initialize(getApplicationContext());` in it's `onCreate()`. I do not call `resumeSession(...)` from anywhere...

Comment: Did you try entering the information and hitting SignUp button? Was there any exception thrown? I believe you are following this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/tutorial-android-aws-mobile-notes-auth.html ?

Comment: @Karthikeyan It ended up having to do with the themes (colours) of the app. Once I reverted from my custom theme to the default `AppTheme`, the AWS UI was working as expected. Will look into it more and post an answer soon.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue had to do with the theme settings on the app, specifically fonts, which cause the built-in UI to act weirdly. I fixed it by ensuring that the `AuthenticatorActivity` which called the built-in sign in layout used default font types and settings.